# How to use selection sort algorithm correctly to sort a list?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, selection

I cannot get this to work, seems like whatever I do it never sorts correctly.

I am trying to sort in a descending order based on number of points.

```
Bryan_Bickell         2    5    +2

Brandon_Bolig         0    3     0

Dave_Bolland          4    2    -1

Sheldon_Brookbank     0    4   -1

Daniel_Carcillo       0    1    +3
```

The middle column is the amount of points.

I am using 4 arrays to store all of those values, how would I correctly utilize the array selection sort to get it to order in the right way?

I had tried all the answers below but none of them seemed to work, this is what i have so far

```
void sortArrays( string playerNames[], int goals[], int assists[], int rating[], int numPlayers )
{
int temp, imin;
int points[numPlayers];

 for(int j = 0; j < numPlayers; j++)
    {
        points[j] = goals[j] + assists[j];
    }

    imin = points[0];

for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
{
  if (points[i] < imin)
  {
        imin = points[i];
   }
}

 for(int j = 1; j < numPlayers; j++)
{
    if (points[j] > imin)
    {
        temp = points[j];
          points[j] = points[j-1];
               points[j-1] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i guess you need to revise your thinking...selection sort deals with finding the minimum value in each iteration...your are not setting any minimum...pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362640/java-selection-sort-algorithm?rq=1

Comment: Your "swap" is buggy; note that the variable `temp` is never set.  Also, your code looks like it's part of a bubble sort, not a selection sort.

Comment: There is `std::swap` for this ;) -> `using std::swap;` ... `swap(points[i], points[i+1]);`

Comment: If you've got 4 parallel arrays, your swapping code needs to work on all 4 arrays in parallel.  You'd do better with one array of structures; presumably, you haven't covered that yet.

Comment: I want to first get the sort to sort out the points, then handling all 4 arrays would be a breeze after function is down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should go like this...

```
void selsort(int *a,int size)
{
   int i,j,imin,temp;
   //cnt++;
   for(j=0;j<size;j++)
   {
       //cnt+=2;
       imin=j;
       for(i=j+1;i<size;i++)
       {
           //cnt+=2;
          if(a[i]<a[imin])
          {
             //cnt++;
             imin=i;
          }
        }

        if(imin!=j)
        {
            //cnt+=3;
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[imin];
            a[imin]=temp;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: a will be your required array

Comment: shouldn't i be j<size-1? otherwise the last i=j+1 will exceed array bounds

Comment: call is something like this...`for(i=0;i<ip;i++)
    a[i]=i;
   selsort(a,ip);`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 4 arrays to store those records if only the middle column is used for sorting, i.e, keys used for sorting the records. From my understanding, you are trying to sort those records of people based on the number of points with selection sort. Code should look like the following: assuming `records` is your array of records

```
void selectionSort(RECORD records[], int n) {
  int i, j, minIndex, tmp;    
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        maxIndex = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)  //find the current max
        {
              if (records[j].point > records[minIndex].point)
              {
                    //assume point is the number of point, middle column
                    minIndex = j;
              }
        }

        //put current max point record at correct position
        if (minIndex != i) {
              tmp = records[i];
              records[i] = records[minIndex];
              records[minIndex] = tmp;
        }
  }
}
```

It will sort all your records in "descending order" as you want

Comment: NB. the `.point` bit isn't correct if using `int records[]` ... I assume that was from another draft using a struct?

Comment: @Useless yeah, I was careless, I meant an array of structs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about store the data into a std::vector then sort it

```
int compare(int a, int b){
 return (a>b);
}

void sort(std::vector<int> &data){
 std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compare);
}
```

try to use vector as much possible, they have been heavy optimized for performance and better memory usage