# Arrange an Array in order by odd or even

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing an online course for basic java programming, and my teacher has assigned me an assignment to let the user chose an number of randomnumbers that will appear on the screen that is going into an array, then that array has to be copied and then that array has to be orderded by even/odd in another array that then has to be printed on the screen.

For example
The user will choose 10 numbers to appear on the screen.
Lets say the following 10 numbers.
586 357 36 843 93 980 902 982 909 998
Then on the following line it should say
586 36 980 902 982 998 - 357 843 93 909
And on the last line how many even/uneven numbers there where
There were 6 even numbers and 4 uneven numbers.

But I have no idea on how to get the array elements to the right place in my code.

import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Assignment 4
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int LENGTH = 1000;
        int[] values = new int[LENGTH];
        int currentSize = 0;
        int quantity = 0;
        double randomnumber = 0;
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;


        System.out.print("How many random numbers between 0 - 999 do you want?");   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        quantity = scan.nextInt();
        while (quantity > currentSize && currentSize < values.length )
        {
            randomnumber = (Math.random() * 1000);
            int rounded = (int) Math.round(randomnumber);
            values[currentSize] = rounded;
            currentSize++;
        }

        System.out.print("\nHere are the randomnumbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(values[i]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        int[] values2 = Arrays.copyOf(values,values.length);
        int[] values3 = new int [quantity];
        System.out.print("\nHere are the randomnumbers in order: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
        {

            if(values2[i] %2 == 0)
            {
                values3[i] = values2[i];    
            }

            if(values2[i] %2 == 0)
            {
                even++;
            }
            else
            {
                odd++;
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(values3[i]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }   
        System.out.print("\nIt was " + even);
        System.out.print(" even numbers, and ");
        System.out.print(odd);
        System.out.print(" odd numbers");
    }
}
```

And I can't use Arraylist or any other methods.

And I now the codeing isnt complete yet, but if someone could just help me out on getting the elements in the second array to be placed in there correct order in the third array.

Comment: ordering require sorting algorithm there are many different sorting algorithm, perhaps selection sort [selection sort stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362640/java-selection-sort-algorithm)

Comment: @Luminous_Dev according to the statement, the idea is just put first the even numbers and at the end the odd... in the same order they were generated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
int[] values = new int[]{586,357, 36, 843, 93, 980, 902, 982, 909, 998};
int[] odds = new int[values.length];
int[] evens = new int[values.length];
int oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0;
for(int number : values){
    if(number % 2 != 0){
        odds[oddCount++] = number;
    }else{
        evens[evenCount++] = number;
    }
}

System.out.println("Odd numbers : " + oddCount);
for(int i = 0 ; i < oddCount ; i++){
    System.out.print(odds[i] + " ");
}

System.out.println("Even numbers : " + evenCount);
for(int i = 0 ; i < evenCount ; i++){
    System.out.print(evens[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another approximation by just slightly modifying your code:

```
int[] values2 = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
int[] values3 = new int[quantity];
int temp = 0;
System.out.print("\nHere are the random numbers in order: ");
for (int value = 0; value<2 ; value++){
    for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
    {
        if(values2[i] %2 == 0)
        {
            if(value==0){
                values3[temp] = values2[i];
                temp++;
                even++;
            }
        }else{
           if(value==1){
                values3[temp] = values2[i];
                temp++;
                odd++;
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < even; i++) //iterate over the first part of the array with even numbers
{
    System.out.print(values3[i]);
    System.out.print(" ");
}   
System.out.print("- "); //Add the separator at the end of all the even numbers
for (int i = even; i < currentSize; i++) //iterate over the last part of the array with odd numbers
{
    System.out.print(values3[i]);
    System.out.print(" ");
}   
System.out.print("\nIt was " + even);
System.out.print(" even numbers, and ");
System.out.print(odd);
System.out.print(" odd numbers");
```

I recommend you to use [System.out.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) to have more compact code, so that, for example in the last part of the code, instead of doing:

```
System.out.print("\nIt was " + even);
System.out.print(" even numbers, and ");
System.out.print(odd);
System.out.print(" odd numbers");
```

you can do:

```
System.out.format("\nIt was %d even numbers and %d odd numbers", even, odd);
```

or simply:

```
System.out.print("\nIt was " + even + " even numbers and " + odd + " odd numbers");
```

or even:

```
System.out.printf("\nIt was %d even numbers and %d odd numbers", even, odd);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was actually what I was stuck on, now I just need to figure out how to get the - separator after the last even number.

Comment: Check the update... in this case iterate the array only for even numbers... add the separator and then iterate over the array only for the odd numbers